# c# nested class datatype accessing parent's subclass

Tags: c#, class, model-view-controller, nested, custom-data-type

I have a fairly complex custom datatype with a lot of properties stored in an organized format. The following is just a small section of it, so it might not look like it's necessary to do this, but I have close to 200 properties all in all, I just didn't want to bring unneeded confusion to the question.

In the following model's code, I need to have the property:

```
Chiller.GeneralInformation.PrimaryVoltage
```

Return the following:

```
Chiller.Controller.PrimaryVoltage.Voltage + " / " + Chiller.Controller.PrimaryVoltage.Phases;
```

What is the best way to have that happen?

```
namespace WebQuoter.Models
{
    public class Chiller
    {
        public MyGeneralInformation GeneralInformation { get; set; }
        public MyController Controller { get; set; }

        public class MyGeneralInformation
        {
            public string AssemblyID { get; set; }
            public string PrimaryVoltage
            {
                get
                {
                    return "HELP";
                }
            }
        }

        public class MyController
        {
            public MyPrimaryVoltage PrimaryVoltage { get; set; }

            public class MyPrimaryVoltage
            {
                public string Voltage { get; set; }
                public string Phases { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you feel the need to create child classes here.  Why not just expose the properties you want directly from `Chiller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't see a reason to design it this way, but if that's what you want you need a reference to the parent `Chiller` inside of `MyGeneralInformation`

```
public class Chiller
{
    private MyGeneralInformation information;

    public MyGeneralInformation GeneralInformation
    {
        get
        {
            return information;
        }
        set
        {
            information = value;
            information.parent = this;
        }
    }
    public MyController Controller { get; set; }

    public class MyGeneralInformation
    {
        internal Chiller parent;
        public string AssemblyID { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryVoltage
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format(
                    "{0}/{1}",
                    parent.Controller.PrimaryVoltage.Voltage,
                    parent.Controller.PrimaryVoltage.Phases);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyController
    {
        public MyPrimaryVoltage PrimaryVoltage { get; set; }

        public class MyPrimaryVoltage
        {
            public string Voltage { get; set; }
            public string Phases { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

But this will have problems when you create a `MyGeneralInformation` and `parent` is `null` causing `PrimaryVoltage` to throw an exception.  You could put `null` checks in there  but I personally don't see why you wouldn't just do this

```
public class Chiller
{
    public string AssemblyID { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryVoltage
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}", Voltage, Phases);
        }
    }

    public string Voltage { get; set; }

    public string Phases { get; set; }
}
```